# process the output of a find command with awk

Tags: awk, find, csh

I hope you can help me on this one.

I need to find for a particular hidden file (.myfile), which content is some string like "Hello"

The goal is to print the name of the directory where the .myfile is, followed by its contents.

example of the format

```
DIR1-->"Hello"
DIR2-->"Hello"
DIR3-->"Hello"
```

**My (wrong) approach**

I am using the find command as below:

`find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name ".myfile"`

and as a resutl I get :

```
./DIR1/.myfile
./DIR2/.myfile
./DIR3/.myfile
```

which is the first part of what I want :-). Next I use awk to format the output:

`find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name ".*" | awk -F"/" '{print$2 "-->" $3}'`

```
DIR1-->.myfile
DIR2-->.myfile
DIR3-->.myfile
```

now, I am stuck here since I cannot get the contents of .myfile

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: would `find` + `bash` one-liner be OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but it sounds like this is what you want:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name ".*" -exec awk 'FNR==1{split(FILENAME,f,"/")} {print f[2] "-->" $0}' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this should be ok:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '.*' -printf '%h -->' -exec cat {} \;
```

You can further finetune output of find by providing corresponding options to `-printf` like %f (for filename), etc (see man find, printf section)

Comment: this was my the very first idea (before I wrote the comment under the question), but `%h` will point to the full directory path not the directory name itself